# Why are the contents of this JSON string changing inside of my ajax call?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to pass an array of JSON objects to my controller.  When I insert an alert right before the ajax call the JSON appears to be well formed and all of the variables are populated correctly.  However, when I inspect the payload of the ajax call I see that some of the variables contain nulls.  What could be causing this? Did I make a mistake somewhere in my jQuery?

```
function postToController(instructionsJSON) {
    alert(instructionsJSON); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Traffic/create",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: instructionsJSON,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are seeing 2 different results. The alert has adId, marketName, estimateId... but in the Preview it is Dma, AdID, and Estimate.

Comment: the result that you are console.logging is the result from the server not the same as the results that you are sending the server. Check what your server is doing. Is is supposed to be echoing out what you put in? Then make certain the Estimate var is what you think it is.

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  I thought I was inspecting the payload but actually it was the response.  I used different property names on the server and that was the cause of the nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you're inspecting two different sets of data.

```
alert(instructionsJSON); // the client data

// ...

console.log(result); // data returned from the server
```

If your server should be returning the same data but there's a difference, then it has to do with whatever the server is doing to the data before it returns it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you send data as key/value pair to the server side page. In your case var 'instructionsJSON` is an array of JSON and not a JSON. So it needs to be passed as a key/value pair which will hold this array.

```
function postToController(instructionsJSON) {
    alert(instructionsJSON); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Traffic/create",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { dataFeildName: instructionsJSON },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  That may be the solution to another problem I'm having.  What is dataFieldName? I'll +1 your answer since technically I should accept the other response as the answer to the question asked.